# Rails on Heroku -- no errors logged, works locally, but no response from web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm new to Rails, and I've been experimenting with deploying on Heroku -- I have the very beginnings of an app that works fine locally (https://github.com/axfelix/ffmpegOnIce), for which I've done the various required prep tasks to make it run properly on Heroku (added a buildpack, added a production DB config to use postgres instead of SQLite, wrote a procfile to ensure it'd use puma), and ... it just seems to do nothing.

`heroku ps` reports nothing wrong:

```
$ heroku ps -a ffmpeg-on-ice
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 1000h 0m (100%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb (1)
web.1: up 2021/02/01 15:28:39 -0800 (~ 5m ago)
```

But trying to load https://ffmpeg-on-ice.herokuapp.com/ just results in "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

One clue I have is that the DB doesn't seem to be being initialized properly on Heroku, as when I do `heroku run rake db:migrate -a ffmpeg-on-ice` I get a "could not connect to server" issue. But I'm not sure what more would have to happen here for it to work, and the Heroku logs just show a bunch of GETs. Am I just not running the app on the right port or something?

(This is a new Ruby 3 / Rails 6 project)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you missed `name` and `password` attributes from your config file:

```yaml
# database.yml
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: ffmpeg_on_ice
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  
  # Add the two:
  name: my_app
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Then add set the environment variable. Check out details on Doc [Getting Started on Heroku with Rails 6.x](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6#add-the-pg-gem)

Add make sure run migrate after deployment.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks! I never have an intuitive sense of what parts of these build systems are supposed to "just work" with isolated, autoconfigured DB instances. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help : ) yeah it's a little bit confused at first.

Comment: Seems like it actually needs `username` rather than name... and it's still not working after changing that.

Comment: Aha! Got it! The postgres heroku "addon" wasn't being added to my instance automatically -- possibly because I only declare the `pg` rails gem conditionally for production? So I had to do that, and then I was able to run migrate from the CLI and it's up!

Comment: @serilain Yeah, that should be `username`. Add `pg` only to production group should be ok, I'm not sure where went wrong. And congratulations, it finally works : )